# iOS module Feedback, location and barcode scanning

Tags: ios, swift, gps, barcode

Has anyone used the iOS modules for location (GPS) and barcode scanning, plain old 2d barcodes, using the camera and can discuss the level of accuracy they provide, particularly the location/GPS module.

Think pallet racking, is the location module accurate enough to discern between one pallet location and the the next to the left or right which is no more than 1.5 meters away, 4-5 feet?

Comment: Your topic doesn't sound like it's appropriate here.

Comment: @ElTomato, where then?